# Creating a multi-indexed dataframe from a nested dictionary (several stacks)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Context: I'm trying to create a multi-index dataframe from a nested dictionary. Using an example is easier to explain:

This is a minimal reproducible example of the dictionary I have:

```
{
    'naive_bayes': {
        'classifier': MultinomialNB(),
        'count_vect': {
            'consumer ': {
                'precision': 0.8888888888888888,
                'recall': 0.4444444444444444,
                'f1-score': 0.5925925925925926,
                'support': 18
            },
            'deal_sites': {
                'precision': 0.7241379310344828,
                'recall': 0.7664233576642335,
                'f1-score': 0.7446808510638298,
                'support': 137
            },
            'activist': {
                'precision': 1.0,
                'recall': 0.5,
                'f1-score': 0.6666666666666666,
                'support': 4
            },
            'news_outlet': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 3
            },
            'retailer': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 3
            },
            'influencer': {
                'precision': 0.717948717948718,
                'recall': 0.8,
                'f1-score': 0.7567567567567569,
                'support': 35
            },
            'horeca': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 4
            },
            'own_brand': {
                'precision': 0.5638297872340425,
                'recall': 0.726027397260274,
                'f1-score': 0.6347305389221557,
                'support': 73
            },
            'reviewers': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 1
            },
            'recipe_provider': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 2
            },
            'wellness_community': {
                'precision': 0.6,
                'recall': 0.21428571428571427,
                'f1-score': 0.3157894736842105,
                'support': 14
            },
            'accuracy': 0.6768707482993197,
            'macro avg': {
                'precision': 0.40861866591873924,
                'recall': 0.3137437194231515,
                'f1-score': 0.3373833526987466,
                'support': 294
            },
            'weighted avg': {
                'precision': 0.6595057011837224,
                'recall': 0.6768707482993197,
                'f1-score': 0.6550934639063294,
                'support': 294
            }
        },
        'tfidf_vect': {
            'consumer ': {
                'precision': 1.0,
                'recall': 0.3333333333333333,
                'f1-score': 0.5,
                'support': 18
            },
            'deal_sites': {
                'precision': 0.5485232067510548,
                'recall': 0.948905109489051,
                'f1-score': 0.6951871657754011,
                'support': 137
            },
            'activist': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 4
            },
            'news_outlet': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 3
            },
            'retailer': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 3
            },
            'influencer': {
                'precision': 1.0,
                'recall': 0.02857142857142857,
                'f1-score': 0.05555555555555556,
                'support': 35
            },
            'horeca': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 4
            },
            'own_brand': {
                'precision': 0.7,
                'recall': 0.4794520547945205,
                'f1-score': 0.5691056910569106,
                'support': 73
            },
            'reviewers': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 1
            },
            'recipe_provider': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 2
            },
            'wellness_community': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 14
            },
            'accuracy': 0.5850340136054422,
            'macro avg': {
                'precision': 0.2953202915228232,
                'recall': 0.16275108419893938,
                'f1-score': 0.1654407647625334,
                'support': 294
            },
            'weighted avg': {
                'precision': 0.6096859840982807,
                'recall': 0.5850340136054422,
                'f1-score': 0.5024823183769689,
                'support': 294
            }
        },
        'ngram_tfidf_vect': {
            'consumer ': {
                'precision': 1.0,
                'recall': 0.3888888888888889,
                'f1-score': 0.56,
                'support': 18
            },
            'deal_sites': {
                'precision': 0.5972222222222222,
                'recall': 0.9416058394160584,
                'f1-score': 0.7308781869688386,
                'support': 137
            },
            'activist': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 4
            },
            'news_outlet': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 3
            },
            'retailer': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 3
            },
            'influencer': {
                'precision': 0.8,
                'recall': 0.34285714285714286,
                'f1-score': 0.48000000000000004,
                'support': 35
            },
            'horeca': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 4
            },
            'own_brand': {
                'precision': 0.6785714285714286,
                'recall': 0.5205479452054794,
                'f1-score': 0.5891472868217054,
                'support': 73
            },
            'reviewers': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 1
            },
            'recipe_provider': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 2
            },
            'wellness_community': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 14
            },
            'accuracy': 0.6326530612244898,
            'macro avg': {
                'precision': 0.27961760461760465,
                'recall': 0.19944543785159724,
                'f1-score': 0.2145477703445949,
                'support': 294
            },
            'weighted avg': {
                'precision': 0.603248839218227,
                'recall': 0.6326530612244898,
                'f1-score': 0.5782927331725013,
                'support': 294
            }
        },
        'char_ngram_tfidf_vect': {
            'consumer ': {
                'precision': 1.0,
                'recall': 0.2777777777777778,
                'f1-score': 0.4347826086956522,
                'support': 18
            },
            'deal_sites': {
                'precision': 0.5315315315315315,
                'recall': 0.8613138686131386,
                'f1-score': 0.6573816155988857,
                'support': 137
            },
            'activist': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 4
            },
            'news_outlet': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 3
            },
            'retailer': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 3
            },
            'influencer': {
                'precision': 1.0,
                'recall': 0.02857142857142857,
                'f1-score': 0.05555555555555556,
                'support': 35
            },
            'horeca': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 4
            },
            'own_brand': {
                'precision': 0.5606060606060606,
                'recall': 0.5068493150684932,
                'f1-score': 0.5323741007194245,
                'support': 73
            },
            'reviewers': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 1
            },
            'recipe_provider': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 2
            },
            'wellness_community': {
                'precision': 0.0,
                'recall': 0.0,
                'f1-score': 0.0,
                'support': 14
            },
            'accuracy': 0.5476190476190477,
            'macro avg': {
                'precision': 0.2811034174670538,
                'recall': 0.15222839909371258,
                'f1-score': 0.15273580732450165,
                'support': 294
            },
            'weighted avg': {
                'precision': 0.5671566742995315,
                'recall': 0.5476190476190477,
                'f1-score': 0.47175211595418887,
                'support': 294
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From this, I'm using this code:

```
result_dataframe = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(all_models, orient="index").stack().to_frame()
```

To get an output as such:

```
naive_bayes         classifier                                               MultinomialNB()
                    count_vect             {'consumer ': {'precision': 0.8888888888888888...
                    tfidf_vect             {'consumer ': {'precision': 1.0, 'recall': 0.3...
                    ngram_tfidf_vect       {'consumer ': {'precision': 1.0, 'recall': 0.3...
                    char_ngram_tfidf_vect  {'consumer ': {'precision': 1.0, 'recall': 0.2...
```

However, this is the output I'd like to achieve:

```
   naïve_bayes        classifier Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4
0                     count_vect   consumer  precision       0.39
1                                               recall       0.56
2                                             f1-score        0.8
3                                                    …          …
4                                  reviewer  precision       0.39
5                                               recall       0.56
6                                             f1-score        0.8
7                                                    …          …
8                                 site_deal  precision       0.39
9                                               recall       0.56
10                                            f1-score        0.8
11                                                   …          …
12                                own_brand  precision       0.39
13                                              recall       0.56
14                                            f1-score        0.8
15                                                   …          …
16                                        …          …          …
17                    tfidf_vect   consumer  precision       0.39
18                                              recall       0.56
19                                            f1-score        0.8
34              ngram_tfidf_vect   consumer  precision       0.39
35                                              recall       0.56
36                                            f1-score        0.8
37                                                   …          …
38                                 reviewer  precision       0.39
39                                              recall       0.56
40                                            f1-score        0.8
41                                                   …          …
42                                site_deal  precision       0.39
43                                              recall       0.56
44                                            f1-score        0.8
45                                                   …          …
46                                own_brand  precision       0.39
47                                              recall       0.56
48                                            f1-score        0.8
49                                                   …          …
50                                        …          …          …
```

Note: This is just an example of an output, the values are not the same as the minimal data example I provided with

Is there any way I could achieve this result? It doesn't have to be necessarily like I've shown (can also be column-based instead of row-based like I did here)

Thank you all for your time! Any help is very welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pd.json_normalize` to flatten levels of dicts.

```py
data =  # your given dictionary 
df = pd.json_normalize(data)

# flatten the dicts but then split
#  all columns on `.` into different column levels
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(col.split(".")) for col in df.columns])
df
```

From here we can transpose or unstack

```
df.T
# or df.unstack(-1).unstack(-1)   # pet peeve: unstack sorts, unfortunately
```

This might be closing in towards the result you're looking for:

[image]

It remains to name the index levels and columns.

Comment: That's it brother! Thank you so much! I was using for loops inside of foor loops to create tuples and then use the `MultiIndex.from_tuple` to get the output, but this is much cleaner and faster! Much appreciated :)